# How to read an xml file from a folder with python?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7

I have a an XML file like this:

```
xml_='''\
<author type="XXX" language="EN" gender="xx" feature="xx" web="foobar.com">
    <documents count="N">
        <document KEY="e95a9a6c790ecb95e46cf15bee517651" web="www.foo_bar_exmaple.com"><![CDATA[A large text with lots of strings and punctuations symbols [...]
]]>
        </document>
        <document KEY="bc360cfbafc39970587547215162f0db" web="www.foo_bar_exmaple.com"><![CDATA[A large text with lots of strings and punctuations symbols [...]
]]>
        </document>
        <document KEY="19e71144c50a8b9160b3f0955e906fce" web="www.foo_bar_exmaple.com"><![CDATA[A large text with lots of strings and punctuations symbols [...]
]]>
        </document>
        <document KEY="21d4af9021a174f61b884606c74d9e42" web="www.foo_bar_exmaple.com"><![CDATA[A large text with lots of strings and punctuations symbols [...]
]]>
        </document>
        <document KEY="28a45eb2460899763d709ca00ddbb665" web="www.foo_bar_exmaple.com"><![CDATA[A large text with lots of strings and punctuations symbols [...]
]]>
        </document>
        <document KEY="a0c0712a6a351f85d9f5757e9fff8946" web="www.foo_bar_exmaple.com"><![CDATA[A large text with lots of strings and punctuations symbols [...]
]]>
        </document>
        <document KEY="626726ba8d34d15d02b6d043c55fe691" web="www.foo_bar_exmaple.com"><![CDATA[A large text with lots of strings and punctuations symbols [...]
]]>
        </document>
        <document KEY="2cb473e0f102e2e4a40aa3006e412ae4" web="www.foo_bar_exmaple.com"><![CDATA[A large text with lots of strings and punctuations symbols [...] [...]
]]>
        </document>
    </documents>
</author>
'''
```

Then I placed it into a pandas dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def iter_docs(author):
    author_attr = author.attrib
    for doc in author.iterfind('.//document'):
        doc_dict = author_attr.copy()
        doc_dict.update(doc.attrib)
        doc_dict['data'] = doc.text
        yield doc_dict


etree = ET.fromstring(xml_data) #create an ElementTree object 
doc_df = pd.DataFrame(list(iter_docs(etree)))
```

I would like to just pass the path of the file instead of creating an `xml_data` string variable, any idea of how to do this?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml

You can do:

```
etree = ET.parse(filename)
root = etree.getroot()
doc_df = pd.DataFrame(list(iter_docs(root)))
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this: `etree = ET.parse(xml_data)`and got this exception: `AttributeError: 'ElementTree' object has no attribute 'attrib'`. Where `xml_data` is the path of the file.

Comment: Is `xml_data` the name of a file, or is it just the xml string?  For example, you need to make a file called `my_data.xml` that contains your xml.  Then, call `ET.parse('my_data.xml')`.

Comment: @hunderlem, I think you need to add `getroot()` after parsing in order to work with `iterfind()`

Comment: Good call!  Editing my answer.

Comment: `xml_data` is like this: `xml_data=/path/of/the/file.xml`. In fact I tried both just passing the full path of the file and with a variable that contain the path of the xml, like this: `etree = ET.parse(xml_file) #create an ElementTree object
doc_df = pd.DataFrame(list(iter_docs(etree)))`

Comment: I updated my answer with @Anzel's suggestion.  Your function `iter_docs()` was expecting the root of the parsed tree, which I didn't notice.

Comment: As a general rule-of-thumb: "when in doubt, follow examples from the docs"